# Passing a variable to a view controller loaded using presentViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I have this code inside a block that receives the geoPoint object:

```
UIViewController *mapViewController1 =
                [[BSTGMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSTGMapViewController_iPhone"
                                                           bundle:nil];
PFGeoPoint *currentLocation = geoPoint;
[self presentViewController:mapViewController1 animated:1 completion:nil];
```

How can I pass the geoPoint variable to the mapViewController1 so I can use it on the

viewDidLoad function? I target iOS 5 using XCode 4.6. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside BSTGMapViewController overload initWithNibName to pass parameter

inside BSTGMapViewController.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withGeoPoint:(CLLocation*)userLocation;
```

and implement it in BSTGMapViewController.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withGeoPoint:(CLLocation*)userLocation
{
//usual code of init with nib name
locationhere=userlocation;

}
```

//ur code

```
PFGeoPoint *currentLocation = geoPoint;
BSTGMapViewController *mapViewController1 =
                [[BSTGMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSTGMapViewController_iPhone"
                                                           bundle:nil withGeoPoint:currentLocation];

[self presentViewController:mapViewController1 animated:1 completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

you can override  init method like the following code and send value to new view controller

Declaration in new view interface

```
- (id)initWithTeamCount:(int)teamCount
```

Definition in new view interface

```
- (id)initWithTeamCount:(int)teamCount {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.teamCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",teamCount];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Pass value from first view

```
SetTeamsViewController *vc = [[SetTeamsViewController alloc] initWithTeamCount:self.teamCount];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a property in the viewController which is going to be presented. The type of property will be the type you are going to pass.

After defining the property , you can access it using the object you created in the class which is going to present it.

```
BSTGMapViewController *mapViewController1 =
                [[BSTGMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSTGMapViewController_iPhone"
                                                           bundle:nil];
mapViewController1.propertyName = valueToBePassed;

[self presentViewController:mapViewController1 animated:1 completion:nil];
```

That's it. You can access it in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Write custom initializer for BSTGMapViewController something like below

```
-(id)initWithGeoPoint:(PFGeoPoint *)point
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:@"BSTGMapViewController_iPhone"
                                                           bundle:nil];
   if(self)
   {
       //here geopoint is class member
       geopoint = point;
   }
}
```

And use

```
PFGeoPoint *currentLocation = geoPoint;
UIViewController *mapViewController1 =
                [[BSTGMapViewController alloc] initWithGeoPoint:currentLocation];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Vinodh we need to add  self = [super initWithNibName:@"BSTGMapViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil]; in the custom initializer. because it is responsible for setting up the layout of the view.

Comment: we are overriding  the default init where come this initwithnibname , it is default initializer providie by aple

Answer (score 0):

Change your initialization method : `-(id)initWithNubName:(NSString*)nibName bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundle;` to: `-(id)initWithNubName:(NSString*)nibName bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundle location:(PFGeoPoint*)geoLocation;`

Define a property `currentLocation` of type `PFGeoPoint*` in `BSTGMapViewController`. In the initialization method, set the property to the value that is in the parameter.

In `viewDidLoad` use the property value of the `PFGeoPoint*` object.